# How can i separate the multiple email address in a single cell to all semi colon space so i can send the email

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple emails like 5, 6 stored in one cell. It is arrange in

```
 xxx@gmail.com,hhh@gmail.com,ishd@gmail.com
```

How do I split it with semi colon with VBA so I don't have to manually do that.

Comment: split function using "," delimiter. Then loop the string array produced. Remember to use Trim to get rid of any additional white space.This is a very common query and a quick bit of research should provide you with plenty of examples to help you. If you get stuck with implementing the code and have a specific programming problem then we can help otherwise this is really too broad.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What did you try so far? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve]! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: Start macro recording and do a manual replace `,` with `;`. Then stop macro recording. Done.

Comment: `Range("A1").Replace ",", ";", xlPart`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Sub SplitAll()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xRg1 As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim xAddress As String
Dim xUpdate As Boolean
Dim xRet As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xAddress = Application.ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a range", "Kutools for Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
Set xRg = Application.Intersect(xRg, xRg.Worksheet.UsedRange)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If xRg.Columns.Count > 1 Then
MsgBox "You can't select multiple columns", , "Kutools for Excel"
Exit Sub
End If
Set xRg1 = Application.InputBox("Split to (single cell):", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
Set xRg1 = xRg1.Range("A1")
If xRg1 Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xRet = Split(xCell.Value, ",")
        xRg1.Worksheet.Range(xRg1.Offset(I, 0), xRg1.Offset(I + UBound(xRet, 1), 0)) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xRet)
        I = I + UBound(xRet, 1) + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: hi, is it possible to separate them all in the same cell instead of different?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to replace commas with line breaks.  I'll leave the other answer, because I think that will be more helpful to others who come here sometime in the future.  Use the solution below to do what you want to do (I think this is what you want).

```
Sub ReplaceComma()
Dim rngCell As Range
  For Each rngCell In Selection
    rngCell.Value = Replace(rngCell, ",", vbLf)
  Next
End Sub
```